# How to change status bar style when scrolling through table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I currently would like to change the status bar style when my navigation bar goes from large title to small title during scrolling of a table view. Is there an easy way of doing this?

I have tried to use

```
currentStyle = .lightContent
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

but I can't get it to call at the right time (when the large title transitions to a normal title).

I really appreciate anybody who could help as this is the first app I have ever developed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a TableView, it inherits from the the ScrollView delegate so I would use the following methods:

```
  func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    /* The code that you will be using when the user starts scrolling,
     In your case that woudl be changing your status bar style to another one
    */

}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    /* The code that you will be using when the user stops scrolling,
     In your case that woudl be setting your status bar style back to original
     */
}
```